# Concept Overloading in C++

Tags: functions, c++, overloading

The meaning of **function overloading** is that two or more functions can have the same name but different parameters. In C++20, [`concept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) has been introduced. I found that concepts cannot be "overloaded" as in the following code snippet:

```
template<typename T>
concept is_summable = requires(T x) { x + x; };             //  one parameter version

//  error: redefinition of concept 'is_summable' with different template parameters or requirements
template<typename T>
concept is_summable = requires(T x, T y) { x + y; };        //  two parameter version

template<is_summable T>                                     //  the usage of one parameter version
void foo(T input)
{

}

template<class T1, class T2>
requires(is_summable<T1, T2>)                               //  the usage of two parameter version
void foo(T1 input1, T2 input2)
{

}
```

I am wondering the reason of avoiding two or more concepts which have the same name but different number of parameters in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overloading based on type or number of arguments is never a default behaviour, it's a feature that requires extra complexity to implement.

Without overloading, a compiler (or interpreter) can roughly:

1. Identify the context of a name (usually as part of the parser rules)
2. Look up the name in a table appropriate for that context (e.g. a list of in-scope functions, or in this case concepts)
3. Use the result of that lookup (e.g. compile a call to that function, or an assertion against the appropriate concept)

With overloading, it's no longer a simple name lookup, you need to examine the number of parameters, and do something extra, such as:

- Have a two-part lookup table, by name and then number of arguments
- Perform a "name mangling" step, e.g. internally the name of `is_summable` is `is_summable___1` for 1 argument, `is_summable___2` for 2 arguments

If overloading can be on more than just parameter count, e.g. on the *type* of the parameters, this complexity increases.

Whether this complexity is worthwhile is subjective:

- On the one hand, it allows the flexibility to have variations such as optional parameters without coming up with extra names
- On the other hand, it adds complexity for the *user* because seeing the name `is_summable` might not be enough to understand what is being referred to, since the overloaded variants could be arbitrarily different

It's also worth noting that adding overloading later is probably a safe change, but removing it would not be. Similarly, once overloading is included, it's harder to change the *details* of that overloading. Any code that produces a compile-time error in language version X is generally considered safe to give meaning to in version X+1; but changing that meaning, or making it error, is generally a breaking change, which designers strive to avoid.

So the committee presumably decided the complexity was not worthwhile in this case; but they could change their minds and make it possible later, since that wouldn't break any currently compliant code.